# displaying chess moves in succession

Tags: chess, xskak

I would like to follow up chess moves one by one.
I managed to use the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xskak}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{Chess}


\newgame\largeboard
\mainline{1. d4 e6 2. e4 d5 3. Nc3 c5 4. Nf3 Nc6}
\[\showboard\]


\newgame\largeboard
\[\showboard\]

\mainline{1. d4}
\[\showboard\]

\mainline{1... e6}
\[\showboard\]

\mainline{2. e4}
\[\showboard\]

\mainline{2... d5}
\[\showboard\]

\mainline{3. Nc3}
\[\showboard\]

\mainline{3... c5}
\[\showboard\]

\mainline{4. Nf3}
\[\showboard\]

\mainline{4... Nc6}
\[\showboard\]

\end{document}
```

Is there a simpler way; because writing a whole game this way is very tedious.

Comment: There is a section about looping in the documentation, and there is even an example with beamer in 9.2. xskak and beamer.

Comment: I`ve got a very good answer by Ulrike Fischer in my post [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384810/adding-comments-and-displaying-notations-in-xskak-looping][1]